# I need to extract only one field of each record from a file, but it does not work

Tags: c++, file, field, extract, fstream

I have a text file that contains name, age and gpa of each record. I wrote a function getgpa that should calculate the average gpa of the file (the whole class). The problem is that I can  easily calculate the average gpa of the whole class when I extract field1 (name), field2 (age) and field3 (gpa). But when I try to extract only field3, I have no results. How can I extract only field3 (gpa) of each record? My function to extract is right below. I am using Dev-C++. Your help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

```
int student::getgpa()
{
  double field3, gpa; double sumGPA=0; int count=0;
  string field1; int field2;
  char line[256];
  cout<<"call of the function 'getgpa' " <<endl;   
  ifstream IS ("student.dat", ios::in);

  while (!IS.eof())
   {
     if(IS>>field1>>field2>>field3)  //where the problem is!
     {     
       sumGPA=sumGPA+field3;
       count++;
     }
   }
   IS.close();

    if (count>0)  //just to make sur not to divide by zero!!
    cout<<"gpa of the students:" <<sumGPA/count<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `if(IS>>field1>>field2>>field3)  //where the problem is!` You said extracting all 3 fields works. Where's the problem?

Comment: I believe moving the `IS>>field1>>field2>>field3` right into the while loop would work better than basing it off of `eof`. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5

Comment: I am trying to write just if(IS>>field3) instead of if(IS>>field1>>field2>>field3). Because I only need field3 to calculate the overall gpa of the class. So I don't want to extract all three fields, but only the one I need for my calculations. But it does not work when I do so.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to write just if(IS>>field3) instead of if(IS>>field1>>field2>>field3).

This won't work because `IS` keeps the current position your are reading in the file. When you do `if(IS>>field3)`, extraction fails because the current position in the file is trying to extract field1.

You either need to keep the code the way you have it, or since `field1` and `field2` are not used, change the names indicating they are throwaway variables (also move the if inside the while loop as suggested in the comments because the while loop will be false as soon as extraction fails):

```
string dummy1; int dummy2;
...
while (IS>>dummy1>>dummy2>>field3)
```

Another option would be to use [tellg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) and [seekg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to change the current position of the stream indicator, but if your lines vary in length, this probably isn't a good solution.

Also, another option would be to use `std::getline` and extract each line first and then work with that but I think the way you have it is fine.

Comment: now i got it, I thought that I could make this code a little more efficient by using only field3. Since you explained clearly how IS works, i will keep it as it is.  Thank you for your help and time.